# How to skip enough space between headnotes using fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I've tried many hints however, none of them worked.
Would you help me to fix this? Another thing, please, how can I add a rule under every headnote in every page?

I am using the preamble below:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, dutch]{article}
    
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    \graphicspath{figures}
    
    \usepackage{geometry}
    
    \geometry{
        paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
        inner=3cm, % Inner margin
        outer=3cm, % Outer margin
        bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
        top=2cm, % Top margin
        bottom=2cm, % Bottom margin
        % showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
    }
    
    
    \setlength\parindent{0pt} 
    
    \usepackage{booktabs} 
    
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    
    \usepackage[english]{babel} 
    
    \newcommand{\emptybox}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \noindent\framebox[#1]{\rule{0pt}{#2}}%
  \endgroup
}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    
    \fancyhf{}
    
    \lhead{\begin{minipage}[c]{1cm}
            %\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{image1.png}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[l]{5cm}
            \scriptsize
            %{\scriptsize University} \\
            {\scriptsize Abbi Aled Acupuncture}
        \end{minipage}
        }
    
   \rhead{\emptybox[3cm]{3cm}}
    
    
    
    
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.05mm}}
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{\large Clinical Record \\ Anamnesis in Traditional Chinese Medicine}\\
    \end{center}
    
    
    \begin{tabular}{l|p{0.728\textwidth}} 
        \toprule
         Name &  \\
         \midrule
         Address &  \\
         \midrule
         Telephone &  \\
         \midrule
         Passport Number &  \\
         \midrule
         E-mail &  \\
         \midrule
         Date of birth &  \\
         \midrule
         Age &  \\
         \midrule
         Marital status &  \\
         \midrule
         Sex &  \\
         \midrule
         Ethnicityt &  \\
         \midrule
         Weight &  \\
         \midrule
         Height &  \\
         \midrule
         Profession &  \\
         \midrule
         Religion &  \\
         \midrule
         Forwarded by &  \\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    
    
    \pagebreak
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

But, I have a problem here:

[image]

Comment: please upload a minimal exmaple which can compile

Comment: Would you please check if now is compiling?

Comment: Please replace `Picture1.png` and `image2.png`, e.g., by an example image of [package `mwe`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe). You can scale it using `scale` or `width` or `height` options to you needs. Or remove the image, if it is not needed to reproduce your problem. Currently we still cannot compile the code. Please see also: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964)

Comment: You should read the `fancyhdr` warning in the `log` file. I would recommend to either use `geometry`'s option `headheight` to change the height of the reserved space for the page header, or use `\smash{\includegraphics[…]{…}` if the image height should be ignored. In both cases, the image could be printed partially outside the page range, if it is too high. So you may also need to increase `top` value.

Comment: Your additional question about a rule under every page header is unclear, because there is already a rule. See the `fancyhdr` manual, if you like to increase the thickness of the rule or want to remove it.

Comment: Hi, @cabohah thank you very much for your attention. I changed the images for an empty box (replacing the figure I intend to add in the headnote). But I still have the same problem with the size of the headnote.

Comment: The log will tell you the minimum height you need to give `geometry`, as @cabohah said. `fancyhdr` prints a warning to the terminal and log telling you what you need here. Then you just put a value at least that big as `headheight` for `geometry`. If it says, eg `14.9998pt` minimum required, put at least `heightheight=15pt` or whatever.

Comment: Off-topic: don't use vertical rules in tabulars which use `booktabs` rules because, as you see in your output, the result is a mess. This is not a bug in the package. Read the documentation of `booktabs` if you want to know the gory whys and wherefores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already told in a comment, you should have a look into the `log`-file of the LaTeX run. You will find there something like:

> ```
> Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
> (fancyhdr)                Make it at least 89.7083pt, for example:
> (fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{89.7083pt}.
> (fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:
>
> (fancyhdr)                \addtolength{\topmargin}{-77.7083pt}.
> ```

This message explains that the space provided for the page header is not high enough for the content used. The height of the page header must therefore be increased. Since you are using the `geometry` package, you should not do this with `\setlength` or `\addtolength`, but rather tell `geometry` the required height in the options. For this purpose, `geometry` provides the `headheight` option (see the manual). In the first step, we assign a suitable value to this option according to the warning:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, dutch]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
  inner=3cm, % Inner margin
  outer=3cm, % Outer margin
  bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
  top=2cm, % Top margin
  headheight=90pt,
  bottom=2cm, % Bottom margin
  % showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
    
\usepackage[english]{babel}% dutch or english???
    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\begin{minipage}[c]{1cm}
    % \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{image1.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[l]{5cm}
    \scriptsize
    % {\scriptsize University} \\
    {\scriptsize Abbi Aled Acupuncture}
  \end{minipage}
}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}
  \large
  \textbf{Clinical Record \\ Anamnesis in Traditional Chinese Medicine}
\end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

But as you can see in the result:

[image: first step without overlap]

Although the overlap between the page header and the page content has now been removed, the header now protrudes beyond the top edge of the paper. (BTW: Almost the same would happen, if you'd use both commands from the `fancyhdr` warning.)

So you also need to move the header down. `geometry` offers several options to, e.g. `includehead`, `headsep`, `top`. You are already using `top`, so I'd suggest to also increase `top`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, dutch]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
  inner=3cm, % Inner margin
  outer=3cm, % Outer margin
  bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
  top=4.5cm, % Top margin
  headheight=90pt,
  bottom=2cm, % Bottom margin
  % showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
    
\usepackage[english]{babel}% dutch or english???
    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\begin{minipage}[c]{1cm}
    % \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{image1.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[l]{5cm}
    \scriptsize
    % {\scriptsize University} \\
    {\scriptsize Abbi Aled Acupuncture}
  \end{minipage}
}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}
  \large
  \textbf{Clinical Record \\ Anamnesis in Traditional Chinese Medicine}
\end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: suggested solution]

(BTW: Almost the same could happen with only the first command from the `fancyhdr` warning. But then the bottom margin would become smaller, too. So you would need to additionally use something like `\addtolength{\textheight}{-88.7083pt}` to reduce the height of the text area and therefore keep the bottom margin.)

Please note: I've removed several code from your example, that is not needed to show the problem or my suggestions. I've also remove setting of `\parskip` to 0, because this is not really recommended and [there are better solutions to not use first line indent of paragraphs](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NoParIndent/) (page also available in [German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_NoParIndent/)). I've also replaced the frame code by an example image of [package `mwe`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe). Every helper has this package installed and it is also recommended for questioners for easy replacement of images.

Comment: Perfect Cabohah, thank you very much. I had another problem with the footnote, but with the information about \textheight you provided, I solved both. 
Congratulations. I read about fancyhdr at https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en. However, I misunderstood the commands.